# Using Cauchy Integral Formula To Solve Integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Would the solution to the following integral:
$$\int_{|z|=1} e^{2z} \frac1z \,dz$$

be 2$\pi$*i* when using Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Also, how would I use the value from this integral to evaluate the following:
$$\int_0^{2} e^{2\cosθ}\cos(2\sinθ) \,dθ$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the solution would be $2\pi i$. Letting $z=e^{i\theta}$, we have $\text{d}z=ie^{i\theta}\text{d}\theta$, and your integral becomes

$$i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}\cos\left(2\sin\theta\right)\text{d}\theta-\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}\sin\left(2\sin\theta\right)\text{d}\theta.$$

Notice that the right integral equals $0$ because it is odd with a period of $2\pi$. Thus,

$$\int_{\left\lvert z\right\rvert=1}\frac{e^{2z}}{z}\text{d}z=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}\cos\left(2\sin\theta\right)\text{d}\theta=2\pi i,$$

giving
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}\cos\left(2\sin\theta\right)\text{d}\theta=2\pi.$$